# Identify id radio button based on database after inflate view android

Tags: android, checked, unchecked

I have 3 file. First MainActivity.java, second is activity_main.xml and third is radio_button.xml.

This is radio_button.xml. I create radioGroup and radioButton in this file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupNotes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioChildNotes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No respond to phone call"
        android:checked="false" />

</RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is activity_main. I create LinearLayout in this xml. Because i want inflate radio_button.xml in this LinearLayout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutRadioNotes"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is MainActivity.java. I just put main function only in this file.

```
void showRadioNote(){
    layoutRadioNotes.removeAllViews();
    if(noteArray.size() != 0 ){
        for(int i=0;i<noteArray.size();i++){
            final View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.radio_button, null);
            layoutRadioNotes.addView(view);
            final RadioGroup radioGroupNotes = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupNotes);
            final RadioButton radioChildNotes = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioChildNotes);

            radioChildNotes.setText(noteArray.get(i));


        }
    }
}
```

I already can show all data in noteArray. But the problem is if i click all radioButton, it will checked all. I want make it can be select one only, mean if i click first radioButton , then it will checked firstButton and get value firstbutton, then when i click second radioButton , it will unchecked firstbutton and will checked second button and get value for secondbutton.

[image: This is my problem, when click other radiobutton it not unchecked others button]

Comment: RadioGroup should be in activity_main.xml, and inflate radio buttons one be one and add them into RadioGroup

Comment: still same .. can selected more then one

Comment: please check my answer, it should be more details; and feel free to leave a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LinearLayout layoutRadioNotes;
ArrayList<String> noteArray = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    layoutRadioNotes = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutRadioNotes) ;
    noteArray.add("test 1");
    noteArray.add("test 1");
    showRadioNote();
}

void showRadioNote(){
    layoutRadioNotes.removeAllViews();
    if(noteArray.size() != 0 ){
        final View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.radio_button, null);
        layoutRadioNotes.addView(view);

        final RadioGroup radioGroupNotes = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupNotes);
        radioGroupNotes.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
            }
        });
        for(int i=0;i<noteArray.size();i++){
            final RadioButton radioChildNotes = new RadioButton(this);
            radioChildNotes.setText(noteArray.get(i));
            radioGroupNotes.addView(radioChildNotes);

        }
    }
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutRadioNotes"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.moduletest.MainActivity">


</LinearLayout>
```

you button layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupNotes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Yes... It worked.. But how can i get value text radioButton when i click on it ?